# AWS Cloudwatch Metrics for DynamoDB/SuccessfulRequestLatency/Minimum return unrecognized "StreamLabel"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch, boto

I am using Boto to pull DynanmoDB metrics from Cloudwatch. But for SuccessfulRequestLatency/Minimum, I got unrecognized "StreamLabel" when i tried to build timeseries object for returned metrics.

I didn't see StreamLabel for this Successful Request Latency in documentation, can anyone has similar experience let me know how to debug?

Comment: Can you add the boto code to your question?